# Meaning of FrameworkType; required for static library

Tags: c++builder, vcl

What does

```
<FrameworkType>VCL</FrameworkType>
```

in the project file do exactly?  When I initially upgrade my projects from BDS2006 to XE5, the project files had `<FrameworkType>None</FrameworkType>` in them. Everything built successfully but I got strange runtime errors that I eventually tracked down to being this setting.

The reason I ask is that in my current project I have some static libraries. The static library project files defaulted to FrameworkType `None`, and the applications/DLLs which link in the static libraries  have FrameworkType `VCL`. Is this correct, or do I need to make the static libraries match the application that is linking them?

Answer (score 1):

A project can target either VCL or FireMonkey, so the framework needs to be specified so the compiler/linker uses the correct libraries.

You should NEVER upgrade a project to a newer IDE version.  ALWAYS create a new project first, then add your existing source files to it as needed.

Comment: Yes, I upgraded at first but then decided to create new projects instead. However, the New Static Library doesn't let you specify a framework type; I just see that it has chosen None by inspecting the project file.  My question is what specific effects this setting has. For example does it actually make any difference to a static library, as opposed to only affecting what the linker does.